Compose view can't be inspected in as layout inspector
When I'm use layout inspector, it will show warning inspecting compose layouts might not work properly with code shrinking enabled
and not show compose layout
in build.gradle
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}

enter image description here
Try to change resources.excludes and minifyEnabled false, but it didn't work.
